# Xamarin Forms Azure App Service ADAL Logout not working as expected

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, adal

We are currently writing a Xamarin Forms Azure Mobile application, using client flow, AAD authentication, refresh tokens etc.
Most of this is working as expected. However, logging out of the application does not work properly. It completes the logout process for both Android and iOS - but upon redirection to the login screen, hitting sign in will never prompt the user with the Microsoft login as expected, it will sign them straight back into the app.

To add a little bit of background, this app has been implemented as per Adrian Hall's book,

current link: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/

with the above described options and configurations.

I have also read through the 30 days of Zumo (also by Adrian Hall) blog on this, and every single post I can find on here relating to this.

My current logout code is as follows:

```
public async Task LogoutAsync()
    {
        var loginProvider = DependencyService.Get<ILoginProvider>();
        client.CurrentUser = loginProvider.RetrieveTokenFromSecureStore();

        var authUri = new Uri($"{client.MobileAppUri}/.auth/logout");
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (IsTokenExpired(client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken))
            {
                var refreshed = await client.RefreshUserAsync();
            }
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
            await httpClient.GetAsync(authUri);
        }

        // Remove the token from the cache
        loginProvider.RemoveTokenFromSecureStore();

        //Remove the cookies from the device - so that the webview does not hold on to the originals
        DependencyService.Get<ICookieService>().ClearCookies();

        // Remove the token from the MobileServiceClient
        await client.LogoutAsync();
    }
```

As far as I can tell, this includes everything I have found so far - i.e. calling the /.auth/logout endpoint, removing the token locally, clearing the cookies from the device (as we log in inside a webview) and lastly calling the LogoutAsync() method from the MobileServiceClient.

Am I missing anything? Or is there a way we can force log out from this environment? As I know you can't "invalidate" an OAuth token, you have to wait until it expires - but to my mind, the /.auth/logout endpoint is supposed to handle this within the Azure environment? Though I'm just not sure to what extent.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, `/.auth/logout` just remove the token store, the original `authenticationToken` could still be authorized, if you call `/.auth/me`, the request is authenticated but you would get the empty response. The `authenticationToken` would be expired an hour after it was created. Based on your `LogoutAsync` method, you clear the `authenticationToken` under the client cache and clear the token store on the mobile backend.

Comment: I assumed that if you use the server flow for logging with AAD, the logout processing may works as expected. As you described that you used client flow, since you have clear the client cache for token, I assumed that the issue may caused by the `LoginAsync` related (MSAL part) logic code, you need to check your code, or you could provide the logging related code for us to narrow this issue.

Comment: I suspect that this is client flow related. Very recently I believe the decision has been made to move away from this particular way of working - integration with either B2B or B2C I believe, which only works with server flow anyway.
I did think of clearing the adal tokencache to see if that would do it, but it's not something I wanted to do.
If you post the server flow comment as the answer I would be happy to accept that - given the information you've provided. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it yet? Could you share me about solution for client-flow at Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are currently writing a Xamarin Forms Azure Mobile application, using client flow, AAD authentication, refresh tokens etc. Most of this is working as expected. However, logging out of the application does not work properly.

I assumed that if you use the server flow for logging with AAD, the logout processing may works as expected. As you described that you used client flow, since you have clear the client cache for token, I assumed that the issue may caused by the LoginAsync related (ADAL part) logic code, you need to check your code, or you could provide the logging related code for us to narrow this issue.